# Is Node.js worker_threads module truly threads or just processes with IPC?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, ecmascript-6, ipc

Recent Node.js versions contain the new module `worker_threads` which is said to bring multi-threading to Node.js. However, it seems using processes underhood: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_new_worker_filename_options

A worker is created from file, and it does actually have `stdout`, `stderr`. Is Node.js `worker_threads` module bringing in multi-threading or just multiple processes with IPC?

Side thing, JavaScript has built-in worker threads (web workers) but no `require` or `import`, possible to require/import other modules inside the built-in worker threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is those worker threads seem real threads. The proof is that printing `process.pid` out from the main process file and the worker file yields the same value.

Having stdout, stderr confused me at first.